# Create React App not injecting CSS (SCSS) anymore

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

since a couple of days I have a problem, where CRA does not inject SCSS changes anymore.

If I refresh the page manually, the SCSS code change is there and applied to my page.
If I change my JavaScript, the change is detected and the app hot reloads.

I was on the 3.0 version of react-scripts, and now I upgraded to the latest, 3.2.0.
Still, SCSS is not injected.

In case it's useful, here are the packages in my package.json file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.1.4",
    "@reach/router": "^1.2.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "css-vars-ponyfill": "^2.1.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.8.14",
    "dompurify": "^1.0.10",
    "draft-js": "^0.10.5",
    "draftjs-to-html": "^0.8.4",
    "google-maps-react": "^2.0.2",
    "html-to-draftjs": "^1.4.0",
    "i18next": "^15.1.0",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^3.0.1",
    "i18next-xhr-backend": "^2.0.1",
    "interweave": "^11.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "pubnub": "^4.25.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-anchor-link-smooth-scroll": "^1.0.12",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.13.2",
    "react-dropzone": "^10.1.5",
    "react-ga": "^2.5.7",
    "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
    "react-i18next": "^10.9.0",
    "react-image-crop": "^8.2.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.8.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.0.3",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0",
    "react-scroll-up": "^1.3.3",
    "react-tooltip": "^3.10.0",
    "react-twitter-embed": "^2.0.8",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "uniqid": "^5.0.3"
  },
}
```

Does anybody have any idea what might have caused it, or what I might try in order to troubleshoot the issue?

edit: I have noticed that when I save a scss file, a hot-update.js file is added to the DOM. this file contains my css changes, but they do not take effect.

Answer (score 0):

so the issue seemed to be related to the fact that i was injecting some code in the head of the document (for the favicons) just before the app was loaded, following a fetch on a server containing the favicon urls.
Removing this fixed the HMR. Thanks for your help